# R error: "Arguments imply differing number of rows"--but upon inspection the sizes are the same

Tags: r, dataframe, join, rstudio

Using the MatchIt package in R to sample a control group based on propensity, now I am attempting to join the selected entries back with the original data and am receiving this error saying the row numbers are unequal, however when I print these sets individually they clearly both have 4,558 rows.

Here's the line of code causing the error:

```
SPS_HV_T_C_M<-inner_join(SPS_HV_Phase_1_2_c[which(SPS_HV_Phase_1_2_c$STUDY_DATE==x[1]),],select(match.data(segment_1),HH,weights),by=c('HH'='HH'))
```

Here's the text of the error:

```
Error in data.frame(..., check.names = FALSE) : 
arguments imply differing number of rows: 0, 4558
```

The issue appears to be in this piece of data: *SPS_HV_Phase_1_2_c[which(SPS_HV_Phase_1_2_c$STUDY_DATE==x[1]),]*, which is simply selecting a subset of the original data which I know cooresponds with *segment_1*: output of the MatchIt algorithm.

When I print this data it clearly shows 4,558 rows, but I am still getting an error showing 0--does anyone have an idea what could be going on here?

Comment: Is there a way you can provide a reproducible example? The error is clear enough by itself, so it would help to see context of why you're seeing it here.

Comment: @r2evans Not really because it's the result of an algorithm run on 50K rows/12 variables of proprietary data. I've figured out that it's the match.data() function which is causing the error but don't know why. If I run MatchIt "manually' for one slice, match.data() returns the  desired dataset, but when I loop through all the slices of data and either use the assign function, or initialize a list and save the MatchIt objects to elements of a list this function stops working and gives the error described above. Other match it functions still work (summary, print, etc.)

Comment: @r2evans TLDR: I have 10 different dates I need to run this algorithm on. If I pick any random date and return the result to a variable everything works great. When I loop through the dates and assign to different variables on the fly then things seem to break.

I guess at this point I could copy and paste the code 10x and do it explicitly but my pride is getting in the way

Comment: Are you using a tibble, by any chance? `MatchIt` doesn't work well with tibbles.

Comment: @Noah I don't think so. I'm initializing an empty list like this: `matchIT_list= vector(mode='list')`  Then I'm assigning the result of MatchIt to a variable: **x** , then putting **x** in the list like this: `matchIT_list[[i]] <- x`.  When trying to use the MatchIt objects in the list I run into problems, but none of these problems exist when directly working with the value of **x** from the last iteration of the loop

Comment: @Noah I should also add that this is in a for loop where **i** increments several times. Specifically the problem I'm still having is if I run `match.data(x)` everything is fine, but `match.data(matchIT_list[[1]])` results in the error implying different numbers of rows. Assume in this example that from my perspective **x** and **matchIT_list[[1]]** are literally the same object which is why I'm still stuck on this

Comment: Figured out a workaround where I just use ```match.data(x)``` from inside the loop and save that to a global list. Still no idea what the problem was but this gets around it.